# Change the commandbutton to ReyCommand in VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm beginner in the VB6.
I am trying to create an application which contains some button. I used a commandbutton.
I want to know how can i change the  the button form commandbutton to ReyCommand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making an assumption that ReyCommand is a third party ocx for VB6. You can't change a control. You need to delete the control you don't want and add the control you want. Make a note of the Text, Top, Left, Width, Height, and other other properties if you want to duplicate the current control. Click on the control you don't want and delete it. Then add the control you do want and set the properties. If you had events coded for the deleted control you will have to move that code to the new control.

If ReyCommand is not in already your toolbox, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the Components window. You'll need to find and check the ReyCommand to add it to the toolbox.

Comment: I didn't find the ReyCommand in the toolbox, how can i add it ?

Comment: Did you try finding and selecting it in the Components window?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't find it in the Components window

Comment: Again, assuming it's installed somewhere on the computer, you can try clicking the Browse button in the Components window and locating the ocx in the Add ActiveX Control window that opens.